# Asp.net 4.0 in iis 7.5 wont load page under ssl. "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage"

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, jquery

We have developed an online application for our customers. The application works without a hitch in firefox, safari, chrome, ie9+ and mobile browsers. The web page is only publicly available under SSL. Through testing it has become apparent that the page will not load in IE8 (windows xp) this is only the case when using SSL (Works fine in http). The application is developed using JQuery asp.net 4.0 and runs on iis 7.5. The error given is "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage".

I am at a complete loss having tried to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The page is https://lip.specialistsoftwareservices.com

Comment: It works fine on IE8 (WinXP) for me. It is most likely a issue with the settings on your Windows XP machine.

Comment: Works fine for me here too.

Comment: Thanks,
I am still having problems. Multiple clients of ours have raised the issue with ie8 so to test we built a fresh windows xp machine sp3 with ie 8.0.6001.18702 and get "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage". Any ideas what config i can try?

Comment: You *may* get a better response over at the Webmasters StackExchange, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ , I think this type of question fits there more than it does here. I'm using a slightly later version of IE8 in my VM, v8.0.7600 ...perhaps there are some Windows Updates? Can they connect to other SSL sites? Probably also worth inspecting it under Fiddler - see what requests are running OK and what is failing.